# ¿Existe una referencia para saber todos los caracteres que deben ser escapados en expresiones regulares?

Tags: regex

En un código (Java) debo extraer una serie de caracteres de una cadena.

Este es el código que estoy usando:

```
html=html.replaceAll("[«»\"\'“”¿?]","");
```

Si intento escapar los signos de interrogación me da error. ¿no deben escaparse los signos de interrogación?

Mis preguntas son dos:

- ¿Existe una referencia (lista) que pueda consultar para saber qué expresiones son obligatorias escapar en REGEX?
- ¿En REGEX el carácter de escape es siempre este `\` o hay otros caracteres de escape?

Comment: Los signos de interrogación están dentro de un set de caracteres. Hay pocas cosas que necesitas **escapar dentro de un set de caracteres**  - \ ]  más -  claro está los caracteres específicos como `\w \d . . . .`  https://regex101.com/r/9nzLHA/1 **No hay que escapar [\^$.|?*+()**

Answer (score 3):

Todo caracter que tenga un significado especial dentro de una expresión regular (como el `.` que representa a cualquier signo, el `*` para indicar cero o más repeticiones, el `+` para indicar una o más, etc...) debe ser "escapado" (con un `\` delante) si quieres que pierda el significado especial y sea el caracter literal. Por ejemplo la expresión regular `\*\+` representa un asterisco seguido de un signo suma.

En concreto, los caracteres especiales son:

```
[\^$.|?*+()
```

En algunos contextos no es necesario "escaparlos", como por ejemplo dentro de los corchetes, pero en general no hace daño escaparlos ahí también y así no hay que andar recordando excepciones.

**Otra cosa** importante, con la que quizás puedas estar haciéndote un lío, es que en la mayoría de lenguajes (Java entre ellos), el carácter `\` es además el que se usa para introducir caracteres especiales dentro de un string, como `\n`, etc... Y entre otras cosas para escapar el propio caracter `"` que de otro modo se tomaría como el final de cadena.

Por tanto, si aparece un `\` dentro de una cadena, Java (o C, o Python) esperan detrás un carácter como `n` (y otros) y le dan un significado especial. Si quieres evitar eso, tienes que escapar el `\` poniendo `\\`.

Si estás usando el `\` para escapar un signo especial dentro de una expresión regular, como por ejemplo en la que vimos antes `\*\+`, y *además* esa expresión regular va dentro de una cadena entre comillas, deberías escapar los `\` que contiene y escribir `"\\*\\+"` no vaya a ser que el carácter que va después el `\` tenga un significado especial para Java (o C) como ocurre con `\n`.

Eso nos lleva a la situación casi aberrante de que si quieres hacer una expresión regular que detecte el `\`, debes escaparlo dentro de la expresión regular y escribir `\\`, y además al ir entre comillas en Java, debes escapara ambos y escribir `"\\\\"`.

### En tu caso

De acuerdo con lo antes dicho en la expresión regular que pones en tu pregunta, el único caracter que necesitas escapar es `?`, y por consiguiente la expresión regular que necesitas es:

```
[«»"'“”¿\?]
```

Aunque al estar el interrogante dentro de unos corchetes no haría falta escaparlo, como dije antes tampoco pasa nada si se escapa.

Pero luego, al meter lo anterior en una cadena Java te encuentras dos problemas:

- Dentro de la expresión aparece una `"` que para Java sería el fin de cadena. Hay que escaparla (pero para Java, no para la expresión regular)
- También aparece el `\` delante del interrogante, hay que escaparlo (de nuevo para java).

Así que tendrías que poner:

```
html=html.replaceAll("[«»\"'“”¿\\?]","");
```

Fíjate que la cadena que realmente recibirá la función es `[«»"'“”¿\?]` y no `[«»\"'“”¿\\?]` (de la misma forma que si pones `"\n"` se guardará un carácter, el retorno de carro, y no dos `\` y `n`).

Comment: Para completar la respuesta, quizás se podría comentar que a veces es necesario escapar el caracter `-` en las clases ya que el guión se puede utilizar para especificar un rango. Por ejemplo `[a-z]` significaría todos los caracteres de la `a` a la `z`. Si se quiere que el guión sea literal, hay dos opciones: (1) Escaparlo con contrabarra [a\-z] o (2) dejarlo como último elemento dentro de la clase (por ejemplo `[az-]`)

Answer (score 0):

no hay expresiones obligatorias a escapar, se escapan los caracteres especiales que se quieran tomar literal.
en tu caso el `?` es un caracter especial.
y si el `\` es al caracter de escape