# Separar un String en un array de String mediante el carácter "\" (Java)

Tags: java, string

tengo el siguiente String:

```
String ruta = "src\main\resources\static\img\actividades\1646784532368.jpeg"
```

Y me gustaría poderlo convertir en un array de tipo String mediante el carácter \ con el método split, es decir:

```
String[] arr = ruta.split("\");
```

Es decir, el arr[0] sería "src".
Pero esto me marca el error "unclosed string literal".
¿Cómo puedo resolver esto? gracias de antemano.

Comment: ponle doble es decir "\\"

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Existe una referencia para saber todos los caracteres que deben ser escapados en expresiones regulares?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/221890/existe-una-referencia-para-saber-todos-los-caracteres-que-deben-ser-escapados-e)

Comment: No me funcionó @RuslanLópez, muestra el error "Invalid regular expression: Unexpected internal error"

Comment: Es que debes hacerlo tanto en ruta como en el split

Answer (score 1, accepted):

debes colocar el carácter de escape para realizar esta acción el código te quedaría así:

```
String[] arr = ruta.split("//");
```

al colocar `//` estas indicando que será una diagonal

La ruta normalmente en windows la se coloca con slash es decir :

```
String ruta = "src//main//resources//static//img//actividades//1646784532368.jpeg";
```

Comment: No me funciona, me sale el error "Invalid regular expression: Unexpected internal error"

Comment: puedes comentar completo tu codigo para verlo

Comment: Mi código es el que esta en la pregunta, si te sirve de algo estoy utilizando NetBeans y el error sale como Warning en rojo

Comment: Esa ruta de donde la obtienes, estas en windows?, el string de la ruta también te aparece mal cierto?

Comment: Sí, estoy en Windows. La ruta es básicamente donde se guarda una imagen que proviene de un formulario, pero quiero poder editar el String de esa ruta para guardarla una Base de Datos y poder usarla como atributo src de una etiqueta <img> en HTML.

Comment: revisa la edicion

Comment: Gracias, ya cambie la ruta y funcionó. Voy a marcar tu respuesta como la correcta.

Comment: Me alegro matias, cualquier otra duda no dudes en colocarla, te agradezco por puntuarme :)

Answer (score 4):

Revisa acerca de los metacarácteres:

Los metacarácteres son caracteres no alfabéticos que poseen un significado especial en las expresiones regulares. que son :

```
\ , ^ , $ , . , | , ? , * , + , ( , ) , { , } , [
```

Revisa: [**Cómo separar un String en Java. Cómo utilizar split()**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/45847/95)

**El carácter '\' es un carácter especial y debe escaparse cuando se usa como parte de una cadena**, por lo tanto usa otro '', para que el carcàcter sea vàlido:

```
String ruta = "src\\main\\resources\\static\\img\\actividades\\1646784532368.jpeg";
```

Para separar los elementos correctamente lo realizarìas de esta forma:

```
String ruta = "src\\main\\resources\\static\\img\\actividades\\1646784532368.jpeg";
    
    String separator = "\\";
    String[] arr = ruta.split(Pattern.quote(separator));
    
    for (String elemento: arr) {
      System.out.println(elemento);
    }
```

Salida:

```
src
main
resources
static
img
actividades
1646784532368.jpeg
```